# if( $a =~ m!Y!i ) What does this mean in perl/cgi-perl?

Tags: perl, cgi

The Code goes something like this:

```
if( $a =~ m!Y!i ){
    $a = "display something";  //some sentence to display
}
```

What does this means in Perl?

Comment: `$a =~ m!Y!i` => `$a =~ m/Y/i` => `$a =~ /Y/i` (if $a contains `Y` and ignore letter case)

Comment: @Сухой27 thanks,got it!

Comment: But don't use `$a` as a variable name. It's dirty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's equivalent to `if ($a =~ /Y/i)`, which is a regular expression testing whether the variable `$a` contains the letter `Y`. The `i` at the end makes the test case-insensitive, so that either upper- or lower-case `Y` will match.